# Sharing a video URL to Facebook using Facebook Android SDK - playback opens the original app?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I have an option in my app to share a video URL to social channels (Facebook in this case). Url will look like a normal link `http://www.my.server.com/video.mp4` and I'm using `com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1` SDK. This is my code:

```
        ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(url))
                .setImageUrl(Uri.parse(thumbnailUrl))
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentDescription(getString(R.string.shared_content_description))
                .build();
        ShareDialog.show(this, content);
```

This kinda works and if you then use Facebook web app, you can play the video. However if I try to play the video from the Facebook app on my phone, it will take me to my app, the one I shared the URL from, instead of playing the video. Is there a way to decouple the posted URL from my app? Can't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: You are using an old SDK version. Try newer versions with proper content model `ShareVideo` as per [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android#videos)

Comment: Interesting, but what if I just want to share URL? And it kinda works as per my message, just not from the phone. I don't want to share the actual video cause it's already on my server at that point and I'd have to download and upload back to FB